# Ruby on Rails where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **worequest** table that belongs to **contact** table.
The **contact** table belongs to the **user** table.

I'm listing the worequest records, but want to limit it to the records for the current user.

This doesn't work:

```
<% Worequest.where(:contact_id.contact.user_id => current_user.id).each do |worequest| %>
```

What would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using through association, e.g.:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :worequests
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :worequests, :through => :contacts
end
```

And then use the following:

```
current_user.worequests
```